# Change attribute value on Associated Products if change on Configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I have a custom attribute who have two options Yes and No. I want if changing attribute value on Configurable Product also change in Associated Products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work on product save event named as "catalog_product_save_after" and get the saved entity id. if it is configurable product and have associated products then compare parent product attribute value with child products attribute values, if found difference, change the value of child product and save them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but will you be able to answer me in more detail about this. Do I need to create a observer? Thank you !

Comment: yes you need to create the Magento observer and in observer get the saved product Id and load that product with product id and check if it is configurable product or not and having child (simple projects). After every conditions fulfill, change the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I create a observer and I solved this.

```
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <stockalert>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>check/observer</class>
                    <method>autoupdatemy</method>
                </stockalert>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
```

```
public function autoupdatemy($observer) {
try{

if($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getData('type_id')=='configurable'){
    $ConfiProduct=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $allProducts = $ConfiProduct->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->getUsedProducts(null, $ConfiProduct);
    foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
        $product->setData('meta_title',$ConfiProduct->getData('meta_title'));
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'meta_title');
        Mage::log('myaddr_new_code after-testingnew-'.$product->getData('name').'--'.$product->getId(), null, 'mage32173.log');
    }
}
}catch(Excpetion $e){
    Mage::log(print_r($e->getMessage(),1),'null','mage32173.log');
}

return;
```

}